# What's causing '<identifier> expected' errors?

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors

I'm sure this has got to be a simple fix but I can't see what I've done wrong. I know traditionally this error means someone has written code outside a method but haven't.

Keep in mind, `Class` and `Frame` are classes I've made and they work fine (I know it's bad to call a class "Class", but I am writing code that creates a UML Class Diagram.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FileScanner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int column = 1;

        Scanner scanner = new(System.in);

        Class object = new("Object", null);

        JFrame f = new JFrame("UML Class Diagram");
        f.setSize(600, 600);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new Frame());
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Error occurs on the `Scanner` object instantiation and `Class` object instantiation lines.

Comment: on which line does this message occur?

Comment: `Class object = new("Object", null)` - what do you expect this line to do?

Comment: "I know it's bad to call a class "Class", but I am writing code that creates a UML Class Diagram." Do you know *why* it's bad to call a class `Class`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Scanner Best Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928616/java-scanner-best-practice)

Comment: @NikNik this is not a duplicate (at least not of that post :) )

Comment: @AMP2010 so why not call your class: UMLClass ? A Class can be a lot of things, a class in school, a class in society, ... the classname should tell you exactly what it is you're working with.

Comment: @Stultuske When someone write: `new("Object", null);`, the question should be close automatically and people shouldn't answer... ;)

Comment: I mean this is only a small project and my lecturer who set the problem said he used a class named "Class" so I didn't think it mattered so much.

Comment: @NikNik have mercy please I'm very tired and a beginner at Java :/

Comment: @AMP2010 he said he used a class named Class. did he also say he wrote it himself? there's a difference in that. I've seen projects where people created their own String and Object classes, and just couldn't figure out why none of the basic functionalities worked.

Comment: @AMP2010 Please read some Java tutorial before posting a question.

Comment: @NikNik I agree that there is some lack of knowledge, but then again, he did bother to 1. ask it decently 2. formatted both question and code 3. provided everything we needed to help him out in a matter of seconds.
My point wasn't that you shouldn't ask for this to be closed, my point was that the 'duplicate' close is a tool for the OP to use. he can then click on the link and find the answer there. Therefor, the post marked as duplicate should indeed contain the answer (or lead to it), which wasn't the case here, that's all

Comment: @NikNik I'm doing a uni course on Java, I made a simple syntax mistake. What's the big deal? I don't get why I'm getting so much flack for being a newbie at Java.

Comment: @AMP2010 Be a newbie is ok but posting simple compilation error isn't. Use some IDE (Eclipse, NetBeans...) instead of simple text editor.

Comment: @NikNik, I am using Netbeans. It provides an error with no further detail than I've given you. I'm sorry if my simple question offends you, but I was staring at this code for half an hour with no improvement. It was a simple fix, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @AMP2010 Keep learning ;) Good luck for your studies!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Scanner scanner = new(System.in);

    Class object = new("Object", null);
```

You say they have to be 'new', but you must specify the type:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Class object = new Class("Object", null);
```

Comment: No. his question on this point is why he's getting the 'identifier expected'.
IMO, Class object = new Class(...); should break the code, but at least he's aware of possible issues on that (as he states in his question)

Comment: Oh my god I knew it was simple. I should have a nap. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to do that.

`Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`

You need to place `Scanner` to specify class type. else you will get Error like

**Syntax error on token "new", ClassType expected after this token**